# Can I change my server's passwords server from a password manager?

Tags: server, password, keepass

I'm working on a project and my goal is to store the passwords of the server in a password manager (to upgrade the security), because most of the servers have almost the same passwords.

The idea is to store the passwords and change them without accessing any server. I found KeePass (and others) but I want to know if is it possible to link the KeePass server to the VMware server to manage the passwords.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a key manager or key manager plug-in. The reason, I believe, is that there's no real benefit from key changes that are so frequent that they become cumbersome to perform manually.

If you need secure remote access to your machines use SSH with public-key authentication. There is no known feasible attack against that method (if used carefully), so there's no need to change them frequently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already know this solution ^^.
This is what my company asked to do that, they dont want to just store the passwords, they want to manage them from a unique interface and also put a unique password for each VM thats why ^^. 
I found many solutions who are very well made (but $$$) and secure but I wanted to know I there is a way to do almost the same things with scripts or stuff like that :)

Comment: PS : there are 150 VM to manage, it will take to much time to update all the password every 3 months if you know what I mean

Comment: If that company wants the implementation of unnecessarily complicated but otherwise useless security policies then they should just shell out $$$ for it. If they can't afford it they should stick to what other people in the open source community are doing which is public-key authentication. That's more flexible and secure than passwords and easier to manage automatically with the tools shipped by OpenSSH. Hopefully my answer comment are a start for you to make an argument that your managers understand (i. e. one about money).

Comment: I don't know what they're paying to have you work for them but I can hardly imagine that you building a half-assed solution from scratch will end up cheaper than buying a suitable password manager or a change of key management policy.